# How to Limit a Parameter in a Method?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a method that I would like to pass an option to, but as a switch. It is hard for me to explain so I will include the class:

```
class Special
{
int Var1;
int Var2;

public void Add1(int option, int variable)
{
    int ToReturn;        
    ToReturn = variable + 1;

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            Var1 = ToReturn;
            break;
        case 2:
            Var2 = ToReturn;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way I can limit the value of `option` to 1 or 2? Can I add any information to the Add1 so that when it is called it informs the programmer as to which values it may be, and what each option does?

I have given an example class, but my class contains many more variables this may apply to.

Comment: why not use `enum` ?

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Ignorance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
public enum Option
{
    Option1,
    Option2
}

public void Add1(Option option, int variable)
{
    int ToReturn;        
    ToReturn = variable + 1;

    switch(option)
    {
        case Option1:
            Var1 = ToReturn;
            break;
        case Option2:
            Var2 = ToReturn;
            break;
    }
}
```

Looks like you want to use enumerations, basically placeholders for statically defined values.

Comment: Thank you guys! Didn't know this existed. Will learn all about them today I suppose!

Answer (score 2):

I could think of a number of ways to do what you are asking however if I was in your scenario (providing I have understood your question correctly) I would be using an enum...

```
enum Options {
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2
}

class Special
{
int Var1;
int Var2;

public void Add1(Options option, int variable)
{
    int ToReturn;        
    ToReturn = variable + 1;

    switch(option)
    {
        case Options.Option1:
            Var1 = ToReturn;
            break;
        case Options.Option2:
            Var2 = ToReturn;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Didn't know this existed. Will learn all about them today I suppose!